# How to select part of complex vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

This is probably a trivial question, but I want to select a portion of a complex array in order to plot it in Matlab. My MWE is

```
n = 100;

t = linspace(-1,1,n);
x = rand(n,1)+1j*rand(n,1);

plot(t(45):t(55),real(x(45):x(55)),'.--')
plot(t(45):t(55),imag(x(45):x(55)),'.--')
```

I get an error

```
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.
```

because the `real(x(45):x(55))` bit returns an empty matrix: `Empty matrix: 1-by-0`. What is the easiest way to fix this problem without creating new vectors for the real and imaginary `x`?

Comment: Please, take your time to take a tutorial on MATLAB, you will greatly benefit from it. This is a problem of misunderstanding basic indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a simple mistake. You were doing `t(45):t(55)`, but `t` is generated by `rand`, so `t(45)` would be, say, `0.1`, and `t(55)`, `0.2`, so `0.1:0.2` is only `0.1`. See the problem?

Then when you did it for `x`, the range was different and thus the error.

What you want is `t(45:55)`, to specify the vector positions from `45` to `55`.

This is what you want:

```
n = 100;

t = linspace(-1,1,n);
x = rand(n,1)+1j*rand(n,1);

plot(t(45:55),real(x(45:55)),'.--')
plot(t(45:55),imag(x(45:55)),'.--')
```